# How flink authenticates to Elastic Search Sink with shield plugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-flink

Elastic Search Version: 2.3.3

Flink Version: 1.1.3

As per these [instructions](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/elasticsearch2.html) for setting up elastic search sink, I inject a Map of configuration data into the ElasticSearchSink. The transport client then uses this to connect.

Since my Elastic Search Server has the Shield plugin we need to authenticate, but in the flink docs there is nothing to mention how this is done.

I did find this on elastic search web site: [Transport client with Shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/_using_elasticsearch_java_clients_with_shield.html)

It has the option "shield.user" in the config, so I added this config option within my HashMap.

```
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
// This instructs the sink to emit after every element, otherwise they would be buffered
config.put("bulk.flush.max.actions", "1");
config.put("cluster.name", "my-cluster-name");
config.put("shield.user", "username:password"); //<----ES Auth here

List<InetSocketAddress> transports = new ArrayList<>();
transports.add(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("172.19.1.57"), 9300));

input.addSink(new ElasticsearchSink(config, transports, new ElasticsearchSinkFunction<String>() {
  public IndexRequest createIndexRequest(String element) {
    Map<String, String> json = new HashMap<>();
    json.put("data", element);

    return Requests.indexRequest()
            .index("my-index")
            .type("my-type")
            .source(json);
  }

  @Override
  public void process(String element, RuntimeContext ctx, RequestIndexer indexer) {
    indexer.add(createIndexRequest(element));
  }
}));
```

However, I still get the following error when attempting to connect:

```
RemoteTransportException[[my-cluster-name][172.19.1.57:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness]]; nested: ElasticsearchSecurityException[missing authentication token for action [cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness]];
Caused by: ElasticsearchSecurityException[missing authentication token for action [cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness]]
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.support.Exceptions.authenticationError(Exceptions.java:39)
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.missingToken(DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.InternalAuthenticationService.authenticateWithRealms(InternalAuthenticationService.java:282)
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.InternalAuthenticationService.authenticate(InternalAuthenticationService.java:184)
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.transport.ServerTransportFilter$NodeProfile.inbound(ServerTransportFilter.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.transport.ShieldServerTransportService$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler.messageReceived(ShieldServerTransportService.java:176)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleRequest(MessageChannelHandler.java:245)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:114)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:75)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ipfilter.IpFilteringHandlerImpl.handleUpstream(IpFilteringHandlerImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm passing the same credentials I use with the http api so I'm assuming they should work. I've also added that user to the transport_client role as per the documentation.

UPDATE: The reason the connection fails is because I need to add in the dependancy for shield plugin within my pom.xml does:

```
<repository>
    <id>elasticsearch-releases</id>
    <url>https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>shield</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm still left with letting the transport client know to use the plugin. There is a public function 'addPlugin' in the static builder class within TransportClient but this object is a private member in the elastic search sink, I'm unsure how to access this function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please open an improvement bug to allow the sink's plugins to be adjusted.